# Geometric interpretation of $\{z\in \mathbb{C} : \text{Im}(\frac{z-a}{b})>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I'm trying to find a geometric interpretation for the set mentioned in the question where $a$ and $b$ are given complex numbers that are not zero. What I've done so far:

$$\text{Im}\frac{z-a}{b}=\text{Im}\frac{\overline{b}(z-a)}{|b|^2}=\frac{\text{Im}(\overline{b}(z-a))}{|b|^2}$$

So to find the elements in our set we need only ask $$\text{Im}(\overline{b}(z-a))>0$$
If we write $$b =b_1+ib_2$$
$$a = a_1 + ia_2$$
$$z= x + iy$$
Then we find that $x$ and $y$ have to be such that:
$$b_1y-b_2x>a_2b_1-a_1b_2$$

After this I find myself stuck. I wonder if anyone can help me interpret this as a geometric place in the complex plane or give some clues as to how to continue. Thanks.

EDIT:
If instead we first try to find what is $\{z\in \mathbb{C} : \text{Im}(\frac{z-a}{b})=0\}$ (with an equality instead of $>0$) then we'll find that $y-a_2=\frac{b_2}{b_1}(x-a_1)$ and this is very clearly a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$b_1y-b_2x>a_2b_1-a_1b_2$$
$$b_1(y-a_2)-b_2(x-a_1)>0$$
$$y-a_2=\dfrac{b_2}{b_1}(x-a_1)$$
this is a line passes through $(a_1,a_2)=a$ with slop $\dfrac{b_2}{b_1}=m$, that shows it is parallel to $O-b$ ($O$ is Origin). If $b_1<0$ the area is half-plane include the Origin, and $b_1>0$ the area is half-plane doesn't include Origin. Thus
$$\left\{z\in \mathbb{C} : {\bf Im}\left(\frac{z-a}{b}\right)>0\right\}$$
is a half-plane with border a line passes through $a$ with slop $m$, includes Origin where $b_1<0$, and doesn't include Origin when $b_1>0$.